# Display element as preformatted text via CSS

Tags: html, css, whitespace, pre

Is there any way to emulate the display of a `pre` element via CSS?

For example, can I keep the whitespace intact in this div by using a CSS rule?

```
<div class="preformatted">

  Please procure the following items:

    - Soup
    - Jam
    - Hyphens 
    - Cantaloupe
</div>
```

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Use `white-space: pre` to preserve whitespace preformatting as in the `pre` element. To go a step further, also add `font-family: monospace`, as `pre` elements are typically set in a monospace font by default (e.g. for use with code blocks).

```css
.preformatted {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="preformatted">

  Please procure the following items:

    - Soup
    - Jam
    - Hyphens 
    - Cantaloupe
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't think to include the `font-family` declaration. +1, for the thoroughness =)

Comment: While I'm waiting to accept this answer, could you explain the difference between `pre` and `pre-wrap`? I assume `pre-wrap`... wraps?

Comment: @GGG: That's right. See [a comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/2TA8g/1).

Comment: @GGG: Exactly. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space

Comment: How do you guys know about this stuff? I spent some time barking up the wrong tree (`display`) but never thought to look at `white-space`.

Comment: @GGG: Call me crazy, but I enjoy studying the specifications on a regular basis.

Comment: @GGG: Experience? Most people don't know about some more niche CSS selectors, like azimuth. Haha.

Comment: @Joshua M: That's a property. One from the long-gone [aural styles](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html#spatial-props) spec, now buried by the Speech module where it quite simply doesn't show up anywhere in level 3, not even in other properties. I bet 9 out of 10 of those who *do* know about `azimuth`... saw it in Dreamweaver's CSS autocomplete. (I did.)

Comment: e: @BoltClock I just read about `azimuth` and it actually sounds pretty cool.... haha. I never used it or knew what it was, I just knew it existed.

Comment: @Joshua M: No clue. I never bothered studying aural styles.

Comment: @BoltClock: Me either, seems pretty useless, can't think of a practical use for it..

Comment: If "azimuth" means the same thing it does in astronomy, it would probably be the direction the sound is coming from, in angular coordinates.

Comment: @GGG: Thats exactly what it is :-)

Comment: and optionally: `word-break: break-all;`

Answer (score 57):

```
.preformatted {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

I think "pre-wrap" is better. It can help with long length in line.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 12):

Yes:

```
div.preformatted {
    white-space: pre;
    }
```

Reference:

- [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 4):

inorder to get `<pre>` you may use;

```
div.preformatted{ white-space: pre ; display: block; }
```

Comment: Why would you need to mess with unicode-bidi? That one seems a little supprising.

Comment: Bit strange for me too!. This is pretty old now. I also can't remember where I referred it from. May be from https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html. Updated the answer since we don't need it now.