# Replace spaces with nonbreakable spaces in JSF

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2

I need some JSF 2.1.29 advise. I have the following using of the bean's property:

```
#{someBean.someProperty}
```

Where `#{someBean.someProperty}` returns `7     8` (note the number of spaces between the digits). And in the browser it's displayed as just `7 8`. When I replace those spaces with `&nbsp;`, then they are displayed as is:

```
7&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;8
```

How can I get to actually display as `7     8`?

Comment: How many spaces are there in the real source of the html on the browser side? Multiple or 1? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753597/display-element-as-preformatted-text-via-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is HTML escaping at work, which is enabled by default. Disable it using the `escape` attribute:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{backingBean.someText}"/>
```

I just tested this, and it outputs `7     8` when the backing bean returns `7&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp8`.

Alternatively, use the [CSS white-space property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to preserve plain (not non-breaking) white spaces:

```
<h:outputText value="#{backingBean.someText}" style="white-space: pre"/>
```

The CSS solution is often better, as it maintains XSS protection.

#### See also

- [JSF 2.0 component to interpret String with HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662851/jsf-2-0-component-to-interpret-string-with-html-code)
- [Display element as preformatted text via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753597/display-element-as-preformatted-text-via-css)

Comment: I'm not certain, @BalusC. He says "Actually, I _would_ replace those space with &nbsp *but* they are rendered by JSF." If you're right, OP just needs to use `String.replace` in the backing-bean. I hope OP will clarify the problem.

Comment: @BalusC No, The answer is perfectly correct. I wasn't aware about it.

Comment: @BalusC BTW, the `<f:selectItems>` tag doesn;t have such an attribute. Is there a quick solution for that case?

Comment: It can be done with just CSS without need for non breaking spaces.