# disable trim more than one spaces in <h:outputText>

Tags: html, string, jsf

I'm making xhtml page with master-detail view pattern. In master panel I use tree component from PrimeFaces. 
Name of child branch must contain 4 nonbreaking space as a divider of brand, colour and year and use  tag for type attribute.
I use  tag with concatenation String in value. Is it possible to use  tag in JSF and more than one nonbreaking space in value ?  Because all spaces are eliminated automatically.

fragment of home.xhtml

```
<p:tree id="tree1" value="#{treeDNDView.root1}" var="node" .... >
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

fragment of Car.java

```
@Override public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    if(year != "")
        result += " brand" + brand + "    ";
    if(color != "")
        result += " color" + color + "    ";
    if(year != "")
        result += " year" + year;
    return result;
}
```

fragment of DragDropView.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="treeDNDView")
@ViewScoped
public class DragDropView implements Serializable  {
    private TreeNode root1;
    private String year;
    private String color;
    private String brand;
    // setters getters
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        root1 = new DefaultTreeNode(new Car("Transport", "", "", ""), null);
        TreeNode cabrio1 = new DefaultTreeNode(new Car("004", "1991", "Red", "Toyota"), root1);}
```

Output example:
brand Toyota color Red year 1991

Need:
brand Toyota (4 spaces) color Red (4 spaces) year 1991

Comment: use `&nbsp;` instead of `' '` in HTML and read about HTML entities ;-)

Comment: Reed about html and multiple species in general. Then read how to solve that and 'port' that to jsf. Lots and lots of info on this in Google and Stackoverflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace spaces with nonbreakable spaces in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239497/replace-spaces-with-nonbreakable-spaces-in-jsf)